# What is the best move in this situation?

Tags: opening, theory

This is my first post on CSE, so I appreciate any guidance on how to frame my questions from now on.

Here is my question: I want to know what the best move is in this sitiation.

```
  [FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.d4 e6 3.d5 ?
```

I was playing Black, and I won this game, but by moving my pawn to d5. a very dangerous situation will be created that can be irritating until the end of the game.

I understand that we should not allow such scenarios, but my specific questions are:

1. How to defend in such scenarios theoretically?, and on the other hand,
2. What lines could White play to win this game (if such a thing is even possible)?

Comment: Note that the overwhelmingly most common move is 2...cxd4, which is the critical test of 2.d4. White then usually follows up with 3.c3, the Smith-Morra Gambit. You can accept this gambit with 3.dxc3 or decline it. The Franco-Benoni that you ended up in is a real opening as well, though it is usually reached by 1.e4 e6 2.d4 c5.

Comment: @dfan Good point. I should have mentioned the normal way of reaching the position. 2...cxd4 is objectively better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but by moving pawn to d5 a very dangerous situation will be created that can be irritating until the end of the game.

It can be dangerous to ***both*** sides. Positions of these type are generally characterized as the **Benoni Defense**. They are unbalanced and offer more chances for complicated play. So you may or may not want to avoid such positions depending upon how comfortable you are playing such positions.

> How to defend in such scenarios theoretically?

A good idea for Black is to immediately take on **d5**, followed by moving the pawn to **d6**, blockading the pawn on **d5**. A sample line of development for Black may go like this -

```
  [FEN ""]

  1. e4 c5 2. d4 e6 3. d5 exd5 4. exd5 d6 5. Nf3 Nf6 6. Nc3 Be7 7. Be2 O-O 
  8. O-O Na6 9. Re1 Nc7 10. a4 b6 11. Bc4 a6
```

The strongest player to consistently play this opening successfully was [Bent Larsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_Larsen). I recommend you take a look at the following games of Larsen to see how Black not only defends this position but also manages to seize the initiative.

[Alberic O'Kelly de Galway vs Bent Larsen 0-1 1967](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1104312)

[Svetozar Gligoric vs Bent Larsen 1/2-1/2 1969](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1308722)

[Wolfgang Unzicker vs Bent Larsen 0-1 1970](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1158920)

[Miguel A Quinteros vs Bent Larsen 0-1 1974](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1115962)

Incidentally, even Garry Kasparov once tried this idea in his early days.

[Yuri Balashov vs Garry Kasparov 1/2-1/2 1979](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1024524)

> What track could white take to win this game almost surely (if such a thing is even possible)?

It is not known yet whether White can forcibly win in this line. Strong players [continue to use this line](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1692312), although it is not popular at the highest level; but that might simply be because of reasons like taste rather than the objective quality of the position.